# JQuery to block the entire page in the content place holder

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have 4 content placeholder from my master page and I am using the 3rd content placeholder. And I am trying to block the entire page. But it blocks only the  3rd content placeholder area. It blocks only the specified area.

I am using jQuery:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        //$().ajaxStart($.blockUI).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
        $('#divConfirmBox1').block({ message: $('#divConfirmBox') });
    });
    $(function() {
        //$().ajaxStart($.blockUI).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
        $('#divConfirmBox').click(function(event) {
            $('#divConfirmBox1').unblock();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Is there any way I can block the entire page?

Comment: see the tick image on the left of my answer. Click it to mark the answer as correct. You can also upvote the answer...

Comment: @prince23: you have never mark your any of question as answer?? Always mark as answer if answers are helpful to for the sake of encouragement. Hope you understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you are specifying an element to block :  `$('#divConfirmBox1').blockui`

To block the whole page you use $.blockui

e.g

```
$.blockUI({ message: '<h1>I block the whole page</h1>' });
```

Comment: thank  you   it  worked .
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $.blockUI({ message: $('#divConfirmBox') });
        });
        $(function() {
          
            $('#divConfirmBox').click(function(event) {

                               $.unblockUI();
            });
        });
    </script>